# Музыкантская колбаса

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов

*Часто меняя места и спускаясь все ниже и ниже, он, наконец, попал на Прогонную и здесь торговал только чаем, дешевою водкой и на закуску ставил крутые яйца и твердую колбасу, от которой пахло смолой и которую сам же он в насмешку называл **музыкантской*** (Чехов, "Убийство").

Давно думал: почему колбаса музыкантская?

Answer (score 2):

Ну первое и очевидное объяснение: тогдашние музыканты в отлитчие от современных были людьми бедными и на многое не претендовавшими.
Впрочем, у Чехова всегда возможен какой-то скрытый подтекст, утверждать наверняка не буду. Например, вообще-то "музыкантская" могло иметь значение "музыкальная" и намекать на последствия её потребления.

Comment: Насчет "музыкальная" да, конечно, мысль такая была. Смутила именно "музыкантская".

Comment: Это возможно для того времени. Вопрос, мог ли рафинированный интеллигент Чехов такое задумать... Вот это сомнительно.